# Problems with TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, android-fragmentactivity, back-stack

Ok i have a `TabActivity` with a `FragmentActivity` in each tab. In one of those tabs i have a root `Fragment` which contains a `ScrollView` with multiples `HorizontalScrollView` like the picture: [image: TabActivity]

In each HorizontalScrollView i add dinamically a few of objects inflated like this:

[image: Item]

To get the effect of Gallery, well the main problem is when I click in each item to replace for another fragment, i add this fragment to backstack, BUT when i press back to return to this fragment all my textview are contains the same text... It's so very strange, and i dont know WHY!? Some ideas?

I put the onCreateView function that i'm using:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if (view == null) {
            this.view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);
         } else {
             ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
         }
        return this.view;
    }
```

Comment: The code you show is insuficient. Where is `view` coming from? `onCreateView` belongs to what? Possibly your problem is that when the fragment is re-created, the state is not restored (maybe not even stored when leaving the fragment) and thus `view` is always `null` and ends up with the same text (which I assume is the text defined in the layout file).